# Replace button with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

is it possible to replace buttons.i.e., button1 with button 2 and so on with out changing the position of the buttons..i also used `$( "#btn1" ).replaceWith( $( "#btn3" ) );` buttons changing in the position two buttons.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AE9Sx/)

```
<div>
    <button id="btn1" class="change-button">A button with some text 1</button>
    <button id="btn2" class="change-button">A button with some text 2</button>
    <button id="btn3" class="change-button">A button with some text 3</button>
</div>

$(".change-button").on("click", function(event){
    var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');
    var buttonText = $(this).html();
    $('#' + buttonId).replaceWith("<span>" + buttonText + "</span>");
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to swap out buttons, or change the text of a button, or replace that button with something else?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by that? Please explain the *problem* you are trying to solve, not the solution you think you need.

Comment: I think you are trying to solve something absolutelly useless here.

Comment: `$('#' + buttonId)` is the same as `$(this)`. Why search for an ID when you have a variable holding the object already?

Comment: If you want to replace a button with a button, use `<button>` instead of `<span>`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this version.

[Fiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/AE9Sx/3/)

```
$('div').on('click', '.change-button', function(event){
    var thisButton = $(this);
    var nextButton = $(this).next('.change-button');
    var cloneButton = thisButton.clone(true, true);

    thisButton.replaceWith(nextButton);
    $('div').append(cloneButton);
});
```

Comment: I wonder if the solution above should clone before replacing?  Seems to work either way.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the buttons `.hide()` and `.show()`. Then they would keep their order.

Or do you really mean fixed position? In that case you want to change the visibility by using `.css('visibility', 'visible')` and `.css('visibility', 'hidden')`.